# React Native, undefined is not an object (evaluating ‘_reactNative.Image.propTypes.resizeMode’)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, video

I'm trying to render video in a React Native component using react-native-video `v5.2.0` . I get following error. I'm using react native CLI on OSX. The app crashes on trying to import the library, line:

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';
```

The error:

```
Uncaught Error
undefined is not an object (evaluating ‘_reactNative.Image.propTypes.resizeMode’)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

The code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

import Video from 'react-native-video';

const Post = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Post</Text>
        <Video
          source={{
            uri: 'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
          }} // Can be a URL or a local file.
          ref={ref => {
            this.player = ref;
          }} // Store reference
          onBuffer={this.onBuffer} // Callback when remote video is buffering
          onError={this.videoError} // Callback when video cannot be loaded
          style={styles.video}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2714), upgrading the version of `react-native-video`  to `"^6.0.0-alpha.1"` would solve the problem:

```
npm i react-native-video@6.0.0-alpha.1
```

Don't hesitate to read the discussion there if it doesn't work for you.