# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Image.propTypes.resizeMode')

Tags: javascript, react-native

i want to use react-native-video, react-native-video-controls

but I got an error

```
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Image.propTypes.resizeMode')
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

```
"react": "18.0.0",
"react-native": "0.69.2",
"react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
"react-native-video-controls": "^2.8.1",
```

did anyone hse solved these issues

Comment: When does this error occur? Can you show us the code, which causes this error?

Comment: Hey Yusuf, can you log the value you are passing as a props for resizeMode ? To be sure that this value is not undefined ? 

https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/API.md#resizemode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native, undefined is not an object (evaluating ‘\_reactNative.Image.propTypes.resizeMode’)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73199062/react-native-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-reactnative-image-proptyp)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

upgraded the react native video to version **"^6.0.0-alpha.1"** ([Github Issue Link](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2714))